# How do I fix my auto indent in Textmate?

Tags: textmate

I'm editing a django template.

When I press enter while my cursor is between html tags:

```
<div|</div>
```

Textmate indents with **three** spaces:

```
<div>
   |
</div>
```

This is driving me crazy. (I want **four** spaces!)

When my cursor is between tags, Textmate tells me that my current scope is

- text.html.django
- meta.tag.any.html
- punctuation.definition.tag.html
- meta.scope.between-tag-pair.html

Where do I find the setting that controls the number of spaces Textmate indents with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a little menu that might display **Tab size: 3** at the bottom of the window. Whatever you set here is supposed to stick.